# How can I exclude some rigid body from rayTest in Bullet Physics?

Tags: bullet-physics, raycasting

I'm trying to picking some object with `rayTest` method of BulletPhysics. The problem is my stage is surrounded with walls (`btStaticPlane`) and the target objects (`btSphereShape`) are in there. And I'm trying to pick with a line from the outside of the surrounding box.

So I have to exclude the planes from `rayTest`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call raytest function from `btCollisionWorld` class it returns all the object your ray hits [(according to this page)](http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCollisionWorld.html). so you just need to iterator over all the collisions and then just pick the ones you want.

you can also create a new instance of btCollisionWorld and call raytest from that instance.